# GeoJSON layers color change on mouseover

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, mapbox, react-leaflet

Hi I am trying to  showcase a leaflet Map in my React page, and it was working a couple days ago but I just came back to it and it is not operating properly. I made a choropleth map and loaded the info from two json files to show on the map, but after looking at it today, the color changes are not working on the map and the mouse hovers are glitchy and only working on the borders, when they should be working on the entire layer. This is my Mapportal.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import L from 'leaflet';
import countries from './countries.json';
import states from './us-states.json';

const style = {
width: "100%",
height: "600px"
};

const mapstyle = (feature) => {
return {
    fillColor: '#FFEDA0',
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
};
};
class Mapportal extends Component {
componentDidMount() {


    this.map = L.map("map", {
        center: [37.8, -96],
        zoom: 4,
        layers: [
            L.tileLayer("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicmFjaGVsb21ib2siLCJhIjoiY2tjODZ6c3UzMTh3ZTJyb2JndHN0dXhlOSJ9.h8aubFClamI3kiUsjIgNTg",
            {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution:
                    'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                id: "mapbox/dark-v10"
            })
        ]
    });

this.geojson = L.geoJson(countries, {
        style: mapstyle,
        onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature
    }).addTo(this.map);

this.states = L.geoJSON(states, {
        style: mapstyle,
        onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature
    }).addTo(this.map);

    var overlay = {
        "Countries": this.geojson,
        "States" : this.states
};
L.control.layers(overlay).addTo(this.map);

}


onEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
    layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name.toString(),{noHide:true}).openTooltip();
    layer.on({
        mouseover: this.highlightFeature,
        mouseout: this.resetHighlight
    });
    layer.on("click",function(e){
        // this gets the id for each country, and we can use that to redirect to different pages since each 
        // json layer has different ids. the states are 1-50, and the countries are their official code
        //window.alert(layer.feature.id);
});

}

highlightFeature = (e) => {
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: "#666",
        dashArray: "",
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    layer.bringToFront();

}

resetHighlight = (event) => {
    this.geojson.resetStyle(event.target);

}


render() {
    return <div id="map" style={style} />;
}


}


export default Mapportal;
```

I am not sure why this is not working. I import the component into my App.js as I normally would but the choropleth just isnt working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You set an initial `color` (for the stroke / border) and [`fillColor`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#path-fillcolor) (for the inner layer area) style options for all your layers in your `mapstyle` function.

But on mouseover, your `highlightFeature` function sets only the `color` style option, therefore unaffecting the fill color.

Comment: That doesn't change anything, I am going by the choropleth leaflet tutorial on the official React site. When I start a new project and start from scratch on a new react app it works, its just in my current one it doesn't, so I'm trying to see if theres anything wrong in my code.